# WinHttpOpenRequest with leading slash in pwszObjectName

Tags: winhttp

When I use **pwszObjectName** with full net path:

```
WinHttpOpenRequest(hConnect, L"POST", L"http:\\.......
```

this function send to server not 
    "**http:\\...**"
but 
    "**\http:\\...**" with leading slash.

How can I delete this first slash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must write just the path to the file, i.e.

```
WinHttpOpenRequest(hConnect, L"POST", L"/path/to/myFile.html", ...
```

Or if you are requesting the main page use just an slash:

```
WinHttpOpenRequest(hConnect, L"POST", L"/", ...
```

This function does not accept full urls.